# How to print each dataframe's row iterating with a message?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` such as: `store_id`, `store_name`, and `number_of_orders`:

```
    store_id                        name cbpr_ordes
0  900004468  [F] | Starbucks | STAR 013          1
1  900038719      Julice Boulangere Pães          1
```

And for each row I would like to print something like this:
"Hello, the (store_id) had (number_of_orders) in the last 15 minutes"

I tried this:

```
for row in df:
    print("Hello, the store_id " + str(df['store_id']) + " had " + str(df['cbpr_ordes']))
```

But I got:

```
Hello, the store_id 0    900004468
1    900038719
Name: store_id, dtype: object had 0    1
1    1
Name: cbpr_ordes, dtype: object
Hello, the store_id 0    900004468
1    900038719
Name: store_id, dtype: object had 0    1
1    1
Name: cbpr_ordes, dtype: object
Hello, the store_id 0    900004468
1    900038719
Name: store_id, dtype: object had 0    1
1    1
Name: cbpr_ordes, dtype: object
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Comment: Just a reminder, f-string is just good for this case, change line inside print() into this:  f"Hello, the store_id {df['store_id']} had {df['cbpr_orders']}", no need to hassle with '+' and 'str()'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use iterrows() function:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
    rows = dict(row)
    print("Hello, the store_id " + str(rows['store_id']) + " had " + str(rows['cbpr_ordes']))
```